# How to increase vertical spacing for lines in \begin{align} block

Tags: align, vertical-spacing

I'd like to know how to increase the vertical spacing for lines in `align`. The sample code is as follows:

```
\begin{align*}
    \left(\left(\psi_{1}\Rightarrow\psi_{2}\right)\Leftrightarrow 1\right) & \,\,\Longleftrightarrow\,\, \left(A_{1}\not \subset B_{1}\,\Leftrightarrow 1\right) \,\vee\,\left(A_{2}\subset B_{2}\,\Leftrightarrow 1\right)  \\
    & \,\,\Longleftrightarrow\,\,\left(\psi_1\Leftrightarrow0\right)\,\vee\,\left(\psi_{2} \Leftrightarrow 1 \right)    
    \\ \medskip
    \left(\left(\psi_{1}\Rightarrow\psi_{2}\right)\Leftrightarrow 0\right) & \,\,\Longleftrightarrow\,\, \left(  A_{1}\subset B_{1}\,\Leftrightarrow1\right)\,\wedge\,\left(A_{2}\not \subset B_{2}\,\Leftrightarrow1\right) \\
    & \,\,\Longleftrightarrow\,\, \left(\psi_{1}\Leftrightarrow 1\right) \,\wedge\,\left(\psi_{2}\Leftrightarrow0\right)
\end{align*}
```

Unfortunately, `medskip` is not working in this case, nor is `vspace`. If two `align` blocks are used, then the spacing between the two would be too big.

Comment: Try putting a length right after the `\\ ` in brackets, e.g., `\\[1\baselineskip]` instead of `\\ \medskip`.

Comment: [1\baselineskip] is too wide. I tried [1pt\baselineskip], but it says `illegal unit measure`.

Comment: `\baselineskip` is already a measurement, and the number there is a multipler. So you can either use `[1pt]` by itself (adjust the number as needed) or use a different multiplier `[0.2\baselineskip]` or whatever you want.

Comment: Within any multiline display environment from `amsmath`, it's important to not leave a space between the double backslash and the open bracket for the vertical space option.  This "trap" was used in these environments to avoid a frequent but spurious error when the first cell in a row begins with a bracketed expression.  (Explained in the `amsmath` user guide -- `texdoc amsldoc`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the optional argument for the linebreak:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{align*}
        \left(\left(\psi_{1}\Rightarrow\psi_{2}\right)\Leftrightarrow 1\right) & \,\,\Longleftrightarrow\,\, \left(A_{1}\not \subset B_{1}\,\Leftrightarrow 1\right) \,\vee\,\left(A_{2}\subset B_{2}\,\Leftrightarrow 1\right) \\
        & \,\,\Longleftrightarrow\,\,\left(\psi_1\Leftrightarrow0\right)\,\vee\,\left(\psi_{2} \Leftrightarrow 1 \right)
        \\[2ex]
        \left(\left(\psi_{1}\Rightarrow\psi_{2}\right)\Leftrightarrow 0\right) & \,\,\Longleftrightarrow\,\, \left( A_{1}\subset B_{1}\,\Leftrightarrow1\right)\,\wedge\,\left(A_{2}\not \subset B_{2}\,\Leftrightarrow1\right) \\
        & \,\,\Longleftrightarrow\,\, \left(\psi_{1}\Leftrightarrow 1\right) \,\wedge\,\left(\psi_{2}\Leftrightarrow0\right)
    \end{align*}

    \end{document}
```

[image]